# Select records within a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure how to frame this question so asking with an example.

From the below table, I want to find out all those records which are not defined with type as 'A'.
So from this table I want to find out the record with ID as 2.

TableA

```sql
+-----+------+
| ID1 | Type |
+-----+------+
|   1 |  A   |
|   1 |  B   |
|   1 |  C   |
|   2 |  B   |
|   2 |  C   |
|   3 |  A   |
|   3 |  B   |
|   3 |  C   |
+-----+------+
```

There is also a TableB, if we want to use.

```sql
+-----+
| ID2 |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
+-----+
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use a `HAVING` clause with a conditional `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT ID1
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID1
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to select all the IDs that are associated to the value you want to exclude.

Then you can use a subquery to filter out those IDs:

```
declare @TableA table (ID1 int, Type char(1))
insert into @TableA 
values
     (1, 'A')
    ,(1, 'B')
    ,(1, 'C')
    ,(2, 'B')
    ,(2, 'C')
    ,(3, 'A')
    ,(3, 'B')
    ,(3, 'C')

;with filteredIds 
as
(
    select
    distinct ID1 
    from @TableA
    where Type ='A'
)
select 
    *
from @TableA 
where
    ID1 not in (select id1 from filteredIds)
```

The result contains only the records that do not have value 'A' (in your example records with ID1=2):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t2.id2
from TableB t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from TableA t1
                  where t2.id2 = t1.id1 and t1.Type = 'A'
                 );
```

With an index on `TableA(ID1, Type)`, this is probably the fastest method under most circumstances.

Note that this also finds ids that are not in `TableA` at all.